# Host WebApi as IIS app so it runs the startup class

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

I can get my api to load configuration when starting the IIS debug configuration. It then runs a hostbuilder and runs my Startup class. However I want to host the api through configuring an IIS app. In this scenario my configuration isn't getting loaded. I could separately load my config. But what is the proper way of hosting a WebApi in IIS?

Clarification edit: I added debug points and error messages to the Program.Main and Startup.ConfigureServices methods. However I cannot debug the api while hosted in IIS and my error messages aren't being written, so it seems these methods are never called. And so essential code to configure the WebApi host is not being executed.

Comment: I still couldn't understand your requirement clearly. Do you mean you want to use web api to modify the startup.cs assembly?

Comment: so is the real question this: When I start my .net CORE server via Visual Studio's debug configuration, my host builder is executed, but not when my .net CORE server is hosted by the IIS server without an IDE?

Comment: how are you deploying your server to IIS? is it on the same environment? how did you create the virtual application on IIS for your server?  is your app able to run at all or is it running in a way that you didn't expect?

Comment: @stephen I'm using VS publish and I just created an application to the publish folder and changed the authentication to enable Windows authentication and disable anonymous authentication.

Comment: Is your app running at all on the IIS machine? Is it configured to run .net core?

Comment: Do you want to debug your deployed project on iis from local visual studio ? Did you know you can remotely debug your hosted project with visual studio ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging?view=vs-2019

Comment: @Jonny Yes, it's all running on the same dev machine configured to run .net core.